# How do I know the application permissions which are required

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest

I added to my application a lot of permissions at first, 
but in the end, I would like to confirm what is necessary , what is useless . 
how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will only need the permission in which you actually use in code. If you are making a camera app, you will need access to the camera, but not the internet. If you are making a web-browser, you will need access to the internet, but not the camera.

What I would do if i were you, is remove all permissions, and only add them as you need them. You do not want to request excess permissions, or your app may look fishy.

Comment: Yes, but if confirm the permission is missing, will cause the application not working.
I am not very clear all the features of the application, but it is required almost all the permissions , so I 'd like to confirm whether it really needs these permissions .

Comment: Yes if you ask the application to do something for you which requires a permission that you do not declare that you need, the app will crash, however, in LogCat, you wil be informed of which permission you are required to use.

Comment: I am not very clear all the features of the application, there is no simple method (not staring LogCat), which is confirm permissions?

Comment: The manifest does not need to be declared and then finalized, it can be changed as you need to add new features. So, as your app acquires new permissions, declare them in the manifest. If i was downloading a web browser that requested access to view and edit my text massages, I would call it fishy. As you said there is no definitive way to see all of the permissions that you require, however, if you do request a package that requires a specific permission, you will see in the manifest why it crashed and what permission you will need to add.

Answer (score 0):

actually, if your app run without needed permissions, logcat will show you what permission is missing. then add it

Answer (score 0):

From my experience the LogCat generally prints an error stating which permission you are missing if you attempt to do something that requires a permission without one.